# What type of intent can be used to find all applications which show any files in directory (like filemanegers)

Tags: android

I save image to Downloads directory in my app and after that offer user to "Show image in directory" and give him a ability to choose app in followed way. What's important, i want that user has ability not only looking this files but has ability to open this ones as well.

```
  private View.OnClickListener onOpenImageInDirectoryListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      Intent firstExtraIntent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.VIEW");
      Intent secondExtraIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

      Uri uri = Uri.parse(
          Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath());
      intent.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder");

      Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Show in directory");
      chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {firstExtraIntent});
      startActivity(chooser);
    }
  };
```

In despite of I have several filemanegers in smartphone only two of It appears.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_RESULT_CODE);
```

Comment: Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT not allows to open files, but only view content of directory and returns URIs of chosen object

Comment: I thought you needed to do this. I didn't understand you question then